How to update a row in EF Core correctly
I have this query that creates a list in C# with EF Core :
 List<DebtCollectionList> debtCollections = 
     _context.Transactions
             .Where(x => x.Status == 0  
                         && x.TransactionDate <= compareDate && !x.Processed)
             .Select(x => new DebtCollectionList
                              {
                                  transaction_id = x.TransactionId,
                                  iin_pan = x.IinPan,
                                  transaction_date = (DateTime)x.TransactionDate,
                                  amount = (decimal)x.Amount
                              })
             .ToList();

And then I do a foreach over the returned rows. I need to change a boolean value after each row has been processed.
What is the best way to update each row within a foreach. I don't really want to run a new context as its already there.
foreach (var debt in debtCollections)
{
}


Remove the .Select and iterate over the Transaction collection returned.

You can create instance of transaction, attach it to the context and mark property as modified. Loading all properties for an update is as bad as O(n) db trips

You can use EF Core 7 ExecuteUpdate:
// collect Ids
var transactionIds = debtCollections.Select(t => t.TransactionId).ToList();

_context.Transactions
    .Where(t => transactionIds.Contains(t.TransactionId))
    .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(t => t.Processed, true));


This would be my recommendation with EF Core 7+, where collecting the transactionIds would be done within your processing loop. For instance if you are iterating through items and conditionally processing them, if they should be marked as processed add the ID to a processedTansacitonIds list, then after you finish processing all transactions (including if an error happens in the loop the list should contain the successful IDs to that point) execute the ExecuteUpdate with the successful processedTransactionIds.
